# How do I parse a VCard to a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a VCard to a Python dictionary using [VObject](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/).

```
vobj=vobject.readOne(string)
print vobj.behavior.knownChildren
```

This is all I get:

```
{'CATEGORIES': (0, None, None), 'ADR': (0, None, None), 'UID': (0, None, None), 'PHOTO': (0, None, None), 'LABEL': (0, None, None), 'VERSION': (1, 1, None), 'FN': (1, 1, None), 'ORG': (0, None, None), 'N': (1, 1, None), 'PRODID': (0, 1, None)}
```

How can I populate the dictionary with my VCard data?

Comment: what does the string you passing look like?

Comment: do you get the same result if you pass `vobject.tests.vcardtest`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to look at the behavior, you want to look at `vobj` itself. The behavior is a data structure describing what children are required/expected, and how to translate those children into appropriate Python data structures.

The `vobj` object is a vobject Component. Its contents attribute is a dictionary of vobject ContentLines and possibly Components, so

```
vobject.contents
```

will give you a dictionary of objects.

If you want a more human readable view of what was parsed, do:

```
vobj.prettyPrint()
```

To access individual children, do, for instance:

```
vobj.adr
```

Comment: Someone seems to have to picked it up and is maintaining it: http://eventable.github.io/vobject/