# How can you remove the new line characters in python?

Tags: python, newline

I am writing a vcf parser and I have the file open but now I need to parse their first name. The file shows "FN:John Smith;;;\n\r" I want to take out the \n and \r. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) function:

```
s = s.rstrip()
```

This will remove all whitespace from the end of your string.

Comment: -1 Two reasons: (a) using `rstrip()` is a kludgeon (cross between a kludge and a bludgeon), it "works" in this case, but extremely bad habit. Safe working habit with text files (when not using csv module) is to discard **ONLY** the newline by using `rstrip('\n')` then splitting or whatever. That way you don't get into trouble when the fields are tab-separated or when you are hunting down variable-width fields that have trailing spaces at the end or the records are fixed-length or etc. (b) Not commenting on the strange `\r` at the end of the OP's data.

Answer (score 1):

If as you say the file shows `"FN:John Smith;;;\n\r"`, then you have a problem -- that `\r` is totally unexpected.

What operating system are you using, what version of Python, and exactly how did you determine that the file shows that?

Here is the usual idiom for reading a file that has lines terminated by the terminator usually used by the OS you are using, and has fields separated by `;` characters:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    # standard OS terminator is converted to `\n` 
    line = line.rstrip('\n') # remove trailing newline
    fields = line.split(';')
    # fields[0] should refer to "FN:John Smith" in your example
    for field_index, field in enumerate(fields):
        if not field:
            continue # empty field
        tag, value = field.split(':')
        print "Field %d: tag %r, value %r" % (field_index, tag, value)
```

You may not have read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) ... I note that "FN" means "Formatted Name", not "First Name", and there's an "N" tag that would be easier to parse:

```
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
```

I also note that a line like `FN:John Smith;;;` doesn't appear in the article.

You may be able to use existing code; see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478027/how-do-i-parse-a-vcard-to-a-python-dictionary).